# "javascript:"-URL as src for HTML <script/> tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In my search for a way to create a local JSONP-compatible URL on the client that  I need to feed into a library function I do not control, I came across a strange behavior exhibited by both Chrome and IE.

While the following HTML works as expected printing the word `hello` on the console:

```
<script src="data:,console.log(%27hello%27)"></script>
```

The next one does **not** work, and in Chrome the network tool says that the request was "(cancelled)".

```
<script src="javascript:%22console.log(%27hello%27)%22"></script>
```

Although in all other circumstances that I tested both URLs (`data:...` and `javascript:...`) shown above produce exactly the same text stream namely `console.log('hello')`.

Is there a documented reason why `javascript:` URLs cannot be used as `src` of an HTML `<script/>` tag? And more importantly is there a work-around, at least for Chrome?

Comment: `javascript:` URL? when using javascript, the script goes between the tags, or in another file identified by `src`

Comment: @WiteHat, `javascript:` URL invokes the script in document's context and returns the string it returns (if any) as the resolving document. Very similar to `data:` URL but more dynamic (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-00.txt), it has existed from the inception of JavaScript.